# Swift. How to scroll a Scrollview (TableView) first to move it to full screen, and then scroll the content itself

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I noticed in some applications the interesting behavior of the scroll. For example, in the Viber application, there is some kind of header view in the “More” menu at the top, below, as it seems to me, is a uitableview table. When scrolling down, the top header is first hidden and the table is aligned to full screen and only then the content is scrolled in it:
[image]

---

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

Moreover, this scroll happens smoothly along with scrolling, even if you swipe a little with your finger and release it, the scroll will continue to move with the same inertia and hide the upper header view smoothly and then scroll through the table itself. How to achieve the same effect?

I tried to do the same using `scrollViewDidScroll`, but it turned out to do only the following:

[image]

At the beginning of scrolling, the table itself scrolls and at the same time, the header view is also hidden, and an increased scroll speed is obtained. Maybe you can somehow do it so that at first the scrolling in the table goes, but the content in it actually remains in one place. Also, when the tableview is scrolled to the very top, then if you scroll it even further, then I would like it to move itself, and not the content in it

My code is following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if y <= headerViewHeight && y >= 0 {
        tableViewTopAnchor.constant = -y
    } else if tableViewTopAnchor.constant != -headerViewHeight && y > headerViewHeight {
        tableViewTopAnchor.constant = -headerViewHeight
    }
}

let headerViewHeight: CGFloat = 150
```

Storyboard:
[image]

I tried to use `scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0` to stop scrolling content in a table in `scrollViewDidScroll`, but then scrolling generally stops working (

I am sorry if such question already exists, but I couldn't find exactly the same. I would appreciate a link and/or example.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: [This](https://michiganlabs.com/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header) will get you most of the way there.